# VirtualBox not detecting processor PAE

Tags: virtualbox, pae, windows-10

This is my system configuration

```
Linux 3.13.0-59-generic #98~precise1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to run Windows 10 in VirtualBox. But I am getting a Windows error stating

> The operating system uses the Physical Address Extension feature to support systems with more than 4GB of RAM. You'll need to use a PC with a compatible processor to run the Operating system

I checked some forums and in the result of `/proc/cpuinfo` the flags are

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr **pae** mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pd
pe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl
```

I am wondering how to I proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I got the answer. I had to update my VirtualBox software to the latest version and there is checkbox for PAE support.